# How can i get one certain row , one line below?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

What i mean is that i have an excel doc with 4 rows

```
   A      B       C        D
1  Data1   Data2  Data3   Data4
2  Data5   Data6  Data7   Data8
```

I want every D row data to get on the below line and become like this.

```
   A      B       C       
1  Data1   Data2  Data3   
2  Data4   // First Data of D row on below line moved on line 2
3  Data5   Data6  Data7 
4  Data8  // Second Data of D row on below line moved on line 4.
```

Can this be done on anyway?

Thanks in advance.
-> I Use Excel 2007 but i would love to know if thats could be done on newer versions of excel.

Edit: So i recorded a macro getting this done for one column.
If i run it back after 2 columns is its done how i want it to.

```
The code of the macro is this:
Sub Μακροεντολή3()
'
' Μακροεντολή3 Μακροεντολή
'

'
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Can you help me get a loop for all columns with step 2 until the end?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, verticals (A,B,C,D) are columns.  Rows are horizontal.  We can't really just do the work for you.  But, yes, it can be done in Excel.  Do you know how to write macros?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Iam completely novice, i dont even know what macros are.

Comment: Google "Excel macros", it's basically a programming language within Excel so you can, for one example, automate complex tasks, like the task you'd need.  I'm afraid it might be a steep learning curve, but hey, it's a challenge!

Comment: hahah. iam afraid of this but i will google it :)

Comment: On second thought, there might be a way with just Excel formulas.  Unfortunately, it's late and I am out of time.  Unless someone else answers, I might have an answer for you tomorrow.

Comment: I can't tell what you want really. You have 5 columns and 3 rows in your first diagram.

Comment: I looks like you might have to invest in some time and learn "macro builders". What you want is a "manual" transformation of columns, via inserting rows and cutting/pasting data from cells. This can be done. But you have to record a macro and build upon it. Test it. Debug it. There was a time when I didn't know this either. It takes time. Or you can pay someone to do it for you. Do some work, get it going and if you get stuck come back to us.

Comment: @sun. This seems to work every 2 columns i do it. So the code of macro is this Sub Μακροεντολή3()
'
' Μακροεντολή3 Μακροεντολή
'

'
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Can you help me get a loop with step 2 from beginning to end?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This formula can be used for your example. It can be used for creating a new table where the "linebreak is added" before every value in last column.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$20,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($F$1)+2)/2,0),COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$1)+1+MOD((ROW($F$1)-ROW()),2)*(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$20)-1)),"")`

`$A$1:$D$20` is the source table
`$F$1` is the first cell of new table

For ranges used above: Insert the formula to cell F1 and stretch to H40. You can adjust formula by replacing range and starting cell address in notepad (CTL+H is your friend).

How it works?

1. See the INDEX function Excel help.
2. The line parameter is: `TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($F$1)+2)/2,0)`, place it in any cell and stretch down - it returns numbers increasing by 1 from 1. This value is same fro every two rows.
3. `COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$1)+1+MOD((ROW($F$1)-ROW()),2)*(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$20)-1))` is little confusing, but it consists from two parts. First: `COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$1)+1` returns only row index in result table. Second: `MOD((ROW($F$1)-ROW()),2)*(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$20)-1))` is "active" only on even rows (because `MOD((ROW($F$1)-ROW()),2)` = `1`, in odd row is `MOD((ROW($F$1)-ROW()),2)` = `0` and multiply last part `(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$20)-1)` which represent row count in source table minus 1. So when this formula is  on even row (in first column), column parameter for INDEX function is `"column index in result table"+1*"column count in source table -1")` what is `1+1*(4-1)` and its index of last column.
4. IFERROR function is used for replacing error codes (when INDEX function is out of range) by `""` it represents blank cell.

[image: Sheet used for creating this answer]

PS: When you stretch the result table to same column count as the source table, you get unwanted values in this last column (it can be prevented by using one more IF function, but the result formula will be much more complex/confusing)

PPS: Sorry for bad English

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and for your time. Iam completely novice at this and tell me please , i have to copy ur code to F1 row is that right? When i copy your formula it gives me an error. Should i do something else? Here is the example [link](https://s31.postimg.org/uwdhf2p6z/new.png)

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but it seems, that you use non-English version of Excel which use different delimeter marks (what I saw in the help buble in your screenshot). Try to use https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/ (I used it for translating the formula to EN, because I have non-English Excel too) In Greek Excel is right notation this: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$20;TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($F$1)+2)/2;0);COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$1)+1+MOD((ROW($F$1)-ROW());2)*(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$20)-1));"")`

Answer (score 0):

@Lluser's answer is impressive.

My answer is maybe simpler.
Again, you can do this by copying the data to another table (or set of columns).

You can use three formulas in three new columns, F, G and H as follows:

```
F1:  =IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0))+1)),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("D",(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)))))

G1:  =IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0))+1)),"")

H1:  =IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C",(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0))+1)),"")
```

And, fill these down to double the number of rows as in the original table.

Therefore, it should look a little like this:

[image]

Some explanation:

1. You find out if the current row is odd or even.  Every odd/even pair in the new table corresponds to one of the original table's rows (this will be true if odd row number "MOD(ROW(),2)=1").
2. If odd row in the new table, then you're taking values from A B and C columns.
3. If even row in the new table AND you're in one of G or H, then you just have an empty string.
4. If even row in the new table AND you're in column F, then you're taking the 4th value (column D) of the original table.

Point 2, is achieved by this:

```
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0))+1))
```

which simply references the row you're targeting.  "Indirect" is Excel's special way to build a reference from a string (like A1, A2, etc.).  In this case, I'm building a string with A and the row number the new table is targeting.

Point 4, is very similar to point 2, except it's working on the second row of the pair, in the new table.

Hope this helps and can be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Under Developer Tab, make sure to turn on "Use Relative References"

- Record Macro
- From A1, go to D1
- Cut
- Go to A2
- Insert Row
- Paste
- Go down to next row
- Stop macro
- Save macro
- Then rerun macro.

[image]

The loop a macro:

Sub Macro1()

**Let x = 0**

**Do While x < 10**

your code

**x = x + 1**

**Loop**

End Sub

Comment: Yes it works. But when i have a lot of data then i need a for loop i guess in order not to run it a lot of times but only once.

Comment: If you want to add a loop then you can modify the macro to put a loop inside the VBA. I put in bold what you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

as i tried all of your answers i followed macro builds on excel. i have done some things and then i got stack so i posted different but still same question on stackoverflow. So here is the answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085058/getting-a-column-on-the-next-row-on-excel-with-macro/38095470?noredirect=1#comment63633911_38095470

```
    Sub ConvertColDtoRow()
'Note that this code is written specifically for column D, but it can be adjusted as needed by changing the column specified

Dim Count As Long, LastRow As Long
Count = 1
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do While Count <= LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(Count,4)) Then
        Range(Cells(Count,4).Address).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(Count + 1,1).Value = Cells(Count,4).Value
        Cells(Count,4).Value = ""
        Count = Count + 2
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Else
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Credits to @RGA.
Thank you all very much for your time.